# No download module to manipulate sound with MP3 in Python?

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I'm looking to make an audio editor using Python for a project in which I'm not allowed to use modules that need be downloaded (I can only do a simple import ).

I want to be able to have users upload a file (preferably in mp3 or some other common format for all operating systems) and be able to play back and edit it. I also need to write out a mp3 file with the new audio.

Would this be feasible in Python 2.7 without outside modules?

EDIT: This will be hosted online if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why not other modules?

Answer (score 0):

Would any of [these audio modules](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/) help?

[audioop](https://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html) is a built-in module to manipulate raw audio data. It requires a format such as .WAV but you could either convert that separately or in the program.

If you want to simply upload wav files to be used with audioop, consider looking at the [wave](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) module.

Comment: How would you convert .WAV file into another format within the Python script?